# Adding records in multiple table using EF6 code first

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 code first approach, i have 3 tables:

1. Product
2. PromotionalOffers
3. PromotionalOfferProduct

I have few products already added inside the products table, now i want that on adding new promotional offer, i should be able to link some products (more than 1) to promotionalofferproducts, but in my case it adds new product

here are my Entities

**Product**

```
 public class Product 
        {
            [Key]
            public long ProductId { get; set; }
            [Required, StringLength(100)]
            public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**PromotionalOffer**

```
public class PromotionalOffer
    {
        [Key]
        public long PromotionalOfferID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public void Add()
        {
            db.PromotionalOffers.Add(this);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

The 3rd table was automatically created by EF based on `List<Product> products` in PromotionalOffer class.

And below is my client code:

```
IPromotionalOffer pOffer = Factory.Instance.Create<IPromotionalOffer>();
            Domain.Product p = new Domain.Product
            {
                ProductId = 1,
                Name = "Colgate",
            };
            pOffer.Name = "Holi";
            pOffer.Products.Add(p);
            pOffer.Add();
```

Though this adds entry in PromotionalOfferProducts it also creates entry in Products table (though it should not add in Product table).

Comment: And what do you expect when you create an instance of the class "Domain.Product"

Comment: I would control many-to-many relation manually rather than allow EF to do it for me.

Comment: Domain.Product p = new Domain.Product
            {
                ProductId = 1,
                Name = "Colgate",
            }; This creates a record in database anyway because entity is fully transferd to a real database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is you are adding a new product
because you create a new instance of Product, instead of using an existing one.

So to solve this, Load your product with entityframework, instead of instantiating your own instance of product.

so in general entityframework terms if you did not use dependecy injection container something like this:

```
var loadedProduct = dbContext.Product.Find(yourProductId);
IPromotionalOffer pOffer = Factory.Instance.Create<IPromotionalOffer>();
            pOffer.Name = "Holi";
            pOffer.Products.Add(loadedProduct);
            pOffer.Add();
```

the reason is, your entity classes is not actually used by entityframework directly, entityframework inherits from your product class and make its own class that it can add more properties to, in order to track the entity. If you create a new instance yourself, entityframework cant track it, and thus assumes its a new product, instead of an existing one, since it is tracking the existing ones that are being loaded.

More ideally i think you need to change your entity mappings so that you can do this the other way around, thus load your product from entity framework, and then add a promotionalOffer to your product, instead of adding a product to your promotional offer.

Comment: Thanks Gerrie, but as you're saying to do it other way round, in my case, promotional offer could be added way later than adding of the product, could you please demonstrate it with an example how my classes should appear?

Comment: how would i add multiple products to the promotionalofferproducts table, also the PromotionalOfferProducts table entity framework has created for me has PromotionalOfferID and ProductId both as primary key, in that case, how would i add multiple products in same PromotionalOffer.

Comment: On second thought I dont think you really need to do it the other way around, because your special offer can have many products. so i think your original idea is actually better. but if you wanted to, just add a List<PromotionalOffer> property to your product.  It might get a bit tricky if your new property is not picked up by entityframework, so then you might need to specify the relationship with the fluent api. so to keep this simple, and on point just add it the way in the example above.